# Access NSMutableArray from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to access an `NSMutableArray` from a different class but when using the following code, there is no value when calling the code.

**TableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imageURLs;

@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "ImageCell.h"
#import "ParseJSON.h"
#import "AsyncImageView.h"

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ParseJSON *json = [[ParseJSON alloc] init];
    [json Parse];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ImageCell *cell = [[ImageCell alloc] init];

    cell.firstImage.imageURL = self.imageURLs[0];
    cell.secondImage.image = self.imageURLs[1];
    cell.thirdImage.image = self.imageURLs[2];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

**ParseJSON.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface ParseJSON : NSObject

- (void)Parse;

@end
```

**ParseJSON.m**

```
#import "ParseJSON.h"

@implementation ParseJSON

- (void)Parse
{
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.delta.rhystowey.com/json/main.json"]];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *imageDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:imageData
                                options:kNilOptions
                                error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *URLs = [NSMutableArray array];

    if( error )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSArray *images = imageDictionary[@"Images"];
        for (NSDictionary *image in images)
        {
            [URLs addObject:image[@"url"]];
        }
    }
    TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    tvc.imageURLs = URLs;    
}
@end
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Note a question ends with `?`

Comment: Seems that's you're creation a totally new `tvc` object. That's not the one you think it is. Check it's pointer, you should be able to see that they're different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a view controller and setting its array. Afterwards, it gets released. Basically these two lines are wrong:

```
TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
tvc.imageURLs = URLs;
```

Change your parse method to return an array.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)parse
{
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.delta.rhystowey.com/json/main.json"]];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *imageDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:imageData
                                options:kNilOptions
                                error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *URLs = [NSMutableArray array];

    if( error )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSArray *images = imageDictionary[@"Images"];
        for (NSDictionary *image in images)
        {
            [URLs addObject:image[@"url"]];
        }
    }

    return URLs;    
}

@end
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ParseJSON *json = [[ParseJSON alloc] init];
    _imageURLs = [json Parse];
}
```